# SQL query joining applications to categories

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I do have large database and my query takes about 2s to complete on production environment which is kinda slow and would like to ask is there a space for improvement?

My initial inputs are `instance_id` with `category_ids` and would like to get all apps grouped by category with status i.e `Active` or `Disabled` and see how many apps are in with that status.

There are 2 tables (MySQL script):

```
CREATE TABLE `app`
(
    `instance_id`       varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `app_id`            varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `is_live`           tinyint(1)                                      NOT NULL,
    `status`            varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT '[INACTIVE|ACTIVE|...]',
    PRIMARY KEY (`instance_id`, `is_live`, `app_id`),
    KEY `instance_id` (`instance_id`, `created`, `status`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `app_categories_apps` (
  `instance_id`         varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `category_id`         varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `app_id`              varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`instance_id`, `category_id`, `app_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin
  ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;
```

and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT ca.category_id, a.status, count(ca.app_id)
    FROM app_categories_apps AS ca
    JOIN app AS a ON (a.instance_id = ca.instance_id AND a.app_id = ca.app_id)
    WHERE a.instance_id = $instance_id
        AND ca.category_id IN ($category_id1, $category_id2)
    GROUP BY ca.category_id, a.status;
```

Result looks like this:

```
|category_id   | status | count|
|------------------------------|
|category_id1  | Active | 1    |
```

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Please see the section on titles in [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The current title applies to any SQL question on the site.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thanks, will improve.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: You probably should ask that on [dba.se], as this is a performance tuning question, not "code review". Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). By the way, if two seconds is "kinda slow", what _is_ your performance target?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a compound key for your PRIMARY key for the `app` table?  That seems nonsensical.  What you're telling the DB engine is that it's allowed to have multiple entries for a single instance_id in the app table, providing that either the app_id or the is_live value are different for each row.  So you could have something like this:

```
instance_id | app_id | is_live
------------------------------
5           | 7      | t
5           | 3      | f
```

That doesn't make any sense to me.  Does it make sense to you?

It seems that the `app` table is confusing two things: instances, and apps.  App IDs should be unique, and instance IDs should also be unique, and presumably there can be more than one instance running for any given app (but each with its own instance_id).

I would recommend normalizing the data, i.e. having a separate table for apps and instances.  (There are cases where normalizing the data can worsen performance, but unless you're dealing with millions of rows and non-indexable range conditions and multiple table joins and lots of queries per second you're probably not in one of those cases.)  Then your apps table can have app_id as a primary key, and your instances table can have instances as a primary key.  But that's based on my assumption of your data model from the names "app" and "instance"; regardless whether my assumption is correct, the data model here should be clarified.

Overall, there isn't enough information here to answer your actual question, about the performance.  You should start with the output of `explain`, but first you need to understand your data model.

Also, IMO this isn't really a code review question.  I would suggest asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ once you have sorted out the points I suggest above.

Comment: Thank you sir, but I did not create these kind of design for that table, it is kinda strange to see this kind of Primary key as well.

Comment: @Marius good to know.  However, if you didn't create this design, then you're *definitely* on the wrong site.  dba.stackexchange.com can help, but you should try to "do your homework" first—in particular, find out how the data model is supposed to work in your prod database, and if it doesn't make sense then propose changes until it does.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any indexes defined in the SQL. [Adding indexes should improve the performance](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/odbc/using-indexes). [The MySQL documentation for indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, but Indexes are generated as I can see in Dbeaver SQL editor under table in indexes folder, they are there. But `app_categories_apps` index is made from all 3 ids (`instance_id`, `category_id`, `app_id`)

Comment: At least it is easy to sneak around the app to add indexes.  When the app doesn't formulate the query optimally, it gets messier.

Answer (score 1):

Flags like those can get in the way of performance, especially when it forces a `WHERE` / `GROUP BY` / `ORDER BY` to have a mixture of tables.

UUIDs are terrible for performance *if* the dataset gets bigger than RAM.

These may help a little by being "covering":

```
ca:  INDEX(category_id, instance_id, app_id)
ca:  INDEX(instance_id, app_id, category_id)
a:   INDEX(instance_id, app_id, status)
```

If the table has only the few columns you mentioned, then you could save a lot of space by packing the UUIDs better.  (36 bytes -> 16 bytes)  See [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)  That will probably save more disk space than your current `COMPRESSED`.  And, since packing the UUIDs is a form of 'compression', doing both won't be very useful.  `COMPRESSED` needs to be un-compressed during the `SELECT`; the UUIDs don't need to (unless you choose to display them in hex).